# Run user created method in an element object from the element returned by getElementById

Tags: javascript, html, javascript-objects

I have created an Object Method in a "Div" DOM Object, I call it squishy.

document.getElementById returns my "Div" Element. How do I run "squishy" from the returned element?

I tried squishy directly but I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'squishy'

Code Below:

**HTML**

```
<div id="div1" class="holathere"></div>
<div id="div2" class="holathere"></div>
<div id="div3" class="holathere"></div>...
```

**Javascript**

```
a = document.getElementsByClassName('holathere');
for(i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
    a[i].soft = 0;
    a[i].squishy = function(a){
       this.soft = a;
    }
}

k = document.getElementById("div1");
console.log(k.squishy(1));
```

Tested in Google Chrome

Comment: It doesn't throw an error for me: http://jsfiddle.net/X8ZH7/1/. However, please see [What's wrong with extending the DOM](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/).

Comment: @FelixKling Hello Felix. Yeah, it doesn't throw an error. Must be something I did with sequence of statements. Maybe i'm running the loop after I called the method. Lemme check. Thankx mate, great article. Hope IE streamlined their DOM.